# Testing state variables with Truffle (javascript)

Tags: truffle-test

I have a contract that defines a struct and has an internal function to create it such as

```
    struct Tokemon {
    string name;
    uint256 id;
    uint256 dna;
    uint32 level;
    uint8 rarity;
    }
        function _createTokemon(string memory _name) internal {
        uint8 randomRarity = uint8(_generateRandomNumber(100));
        uint256 randomDna = _generateRandomNumber(10**16);
        Tokemon memory newTokemon = Tokemon(_name, COUNT, randomDna, 1, randomRarity);
        tokemons.push(newTokemon);
        _safeMint(msg.sender, COUNT);
        emit NewTokemon(msg.sender, COUNT, randomDna);
        COUNT++;
    }

    //EXTERNAL FUNCTIONS ONLY ACCESSIBLE BY OWNERS
    /**
    * @dev Token owner can update the fee
    * @param _fee The new fee
    */
    function updateFee(uint256 _fee) external onlyOwner() {
        fee = _fee;
    }

    // PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
    /**
    * @dev Creates a new random tokemon
    */
    function createRandomTokemon(string memory _name) public payable {
        require(msg.value >= fee);
        _createTokemon(_name);
    }
```

And its corresponding tests:

```
const tokemonNames = ['testokemon', 'toketest'];
contract('TokemonToken', function (accounts) {
  let tokemonContractInstance;
  let [account1, account2] = accounts;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    tokemonContractInstance = await Tokemon.new('TokemonToken', 'TNFT');
  });
  it('should create a new tokemon', async () => {
    const result = await tokemonContractInstance.createRandomTokemon(
      tokemonNames[0],
      {
        from: account1,
      }
    );
    expect(result.logs[0].event).to.be.equal('Transfer');
    expect(result.logs[1].event).to.be.equal('NewTokemon');
    expect(result.receipt.status).to.equal(true);
    console.log(result.logs[1].args);
  });
```

I would like to test that the name of the new created Tokemon is tokemonNames[0]. However, when I log `result.logs[0].args` I cannot see any of the Tokemon properties such as level, rarity, dna, name... which makes it impossible for me to check if those values have been set correctly.
How could I see those contract state values in order to test them?
Is it an effective way of testing the token creation?

```
  it('should create a new tokemon', async () => {
    const result = await tokemonContractInstance.createRandomTokemon(
      tokemonNames[0],
      {
        from: account1,
      }
    );
    expect(result.logs[0].event).to.be.equal('Transfer');
    expect(result.logs[1].event).to.be.equal('NewTokemon');
    expect(result.receipt.status).to.equal(true);
    const tokemons = await tokemonContractInstance.getTokemons();
    expect(tokemons.length).to.equal(1);
    expect(tokemons[0].name).to.equal(tokemonNames[0]);
    expect(tokemons[0].level).to.equal('1');
    const account1Balance = await tokemonContractInstance.balanceOf(account1);
    expect(account1Balance.toNumber()).to.equal(1);
  });
```

Comment: It isn't emitting an event with the name, did you try emitting one?

Comment: Yes, the contract's factory is emitting it like this `event NewTokemon(address indexed owner, uint256 id, uint256 dna);`

Comment: To test the name you can retrieve the tokens details with the `id`, or emit the name with the event.

Comment: So I guess that what I am doing wrong is that my current event does not emit the name property.
It should be `event NewTokemon(address indexed owner, uint256 id, string memory name, uint256 dna);`. That must be it! Thanks
By the way, I am wondering whether memory is really necessary here since it is just an event. Any help on this?

Comment: It is a syntax error to use "memory" for an event parameter.